# Shorter functions in ES2015?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following code (taken from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Shorter_functions)):

```
var a = [
  "Hydrogen",
  "Helium",
  "Lithium",
  "Beryl­lium"
];

var a2 = a.map(function(s){ return s.length });

var a3 = a.map( s => s.length );
```

Is it possible to make it even shorter? E.g.:

```
var a4 = a.map( .length );
```

The above doesn't work (it results in a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`).

So is there any way to do that in ES2015?

Comment: I hope not. The syntax is just wrong.

Comment: No. 12 more to go...

Comment: Why would you even want to do that other than golfing? It makes it much harder to read what's going on.

Comment: There's a difference of 4 characters. I don't understand the point of the question.

Comment: This would mean that a random property access `.prop` should be interpreted as a function taking an object parameter and returning said property of this object. I can't imagine the amount of weird bugs that would spawn, instead of simply crashing ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try to define a proxy object like this:

```
_ = new Proxy({}, {
    get: (t, name) => x => x[name]
});
```

and then

```
var a3 = a.map(_.length)
```

Whether this makes sense or not is another question.

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter syntax would look like

```
   var a4 = a.map(({ length }) => length); // [8, 6, 7, 9]
```

where a4 element will be automatically invoked over length

Comment: Destructuring is nice, however it's 7 characters longer than the `a3` example

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do it like that, because it would be in conflict with the way [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) are used.

From [ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-property-accessors):

> In specification text and algorithms, dot notation may be used to refer to a specific field of a Record value. For example, if R is the record shown in the previous paragraph then R.[[field2]] is shorthand for “the field of R named [[field2]]”.

TL;DR The syntax is incorrect. You can't access a property of nothing without getting philosophical.